# How to build test data builder for json model

Tags: java, json

I have a microservice/application that accepts a JSON and convert to java POJO that is processed further in that application. Say the structure is:

```
{
    "header": {
         "msgTs": "2020-02-20T11:00:00"
    }
    "hazmat": {
          "name": "a"
     } 
     // some other properties
}

public class Hazmat {
    private String hazmatName;
}

public class POJO {
    private Header header;
    private Hazmat hazmet;
}
```

Here the "hazmat" could be present or absent. For all test data, the value of header and msgTs doesn't matter. So we can hard code the value;

Now to test it I would like to create a test data builder. The builder will be like this:

```
public class PojoBulider {

    private String hazmatName;

    public PojoBuilder withHamatName(String hazmatName) { this.hazmatname = hazmatName; return this; }

    public String build() {
        // generate test data from the captured inputs eg "hazmatName".    
    }
}
```

for generating the test data the user input / feature file column value will work with a few selected properties (eg hazmatName). The rest can be hard coded.

Now the problem is how can we hard code the fixed value such as msgTs? I can have a template json:

```
{
    "header": {
         "msgTs": "2020-02-20T11:00:00"
    }
    "hazmat": {
          "name": "%%hazmatName%%"
     } 
}
```

Then have:

```
public void build() {
    String templateJson; // load from file;

    templateJson = templateJson.replaceAll("%%hazmatName%%", hazmatName);

    return templateJson;
}
```

The thing is that the JSON can have properties that are present and absent. So I cannot have multiple templateJson with different possible value ie one templateJson:

```
{
    "header": {
         "msgTs": "2020-02-20T11:00:00"
    }
    "hazmat": {
          "name": "%%hazmatName%%"
     } 
}
```

another template json:

```
{
    "header": {
         "msgTs": "2020-02-20T11:00:00"
    }
    "toy": {
          "name": "%%toyName%%"
     } 
}
```

I can't have one template json as:

```
{
    "header": {
         "msgTs": "2020-02-20T11:00:00"
    }
    "toy": {
          "name": "%%toyName%%"
     }
     "hazmat": {
          "name": "%%hazmatName%%"
     } 
}
```

Because not test data will have both "toy" and "hazmat" section.

So I am stuck. I can probably have multiple template json like one for hazmat, hazmat.json:

```
"hazmat": {
          "name": "%%hazmatName%%"
     }
```

and another for toy:

```
  "toy": {
          "name": "%%toyName%%"
     }
```

and combine them like:

```
  public String build() {   
      if (hazmatName != null) {
          // load hazmatJson
          // append to templateJson 
      }

      if (toyName != null) {
          // load toyJson
          // append to templateJson
      }

      return templateJson;
  }
```

I would like to use the POJO instead:

```
 public String build() [
     Pojo pojo = new Pojo();
     Hazmat hazmat = new Hazmat();
     hazmat.setHazmatName(this.hazmatName);

     pojo.setHazmat(hazmat);

     return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(pojo);
  }
```

but the problem is how can I populate the header, etc value that don't change for all json. I can have another json:

```
{
      "header": { "msgTs": "..." } }
```

and then load it using ObjectMapper load:

```
public String build() {
     Header header = new ObjectMapper().load("header.json");
     pojo.setHeader(header);
}
```

Is there a pure java based approach without using any json file altogether (ie header.json, toy.json, hazmat.json)? how do normally people generate test data in this case?

Comment: Assuming that your JSON does not need to be 'flat' I think you might actually need a builder for it. What I am uncertain of is whether you want to use the string as input. If so, I would create a class for which you can create objects and then print it by some print function. For Json objects such builders already exist.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am not sure I understand "I think you might actually need a builder for it. What I am uncertain of is whether you want to use the string as input. If so, I would create a class for which you can create objects and then print it by some print function". Are you trying to manipulate properties as String and manipulate on a JsonObject  instance? If so, I would prefer to directly access properties by field name ie (.setName()) etc. instead of setProperty("name", name).

Answer (score 0):

As you commented that you prefer to modify fields over Key-based mappings, I write this answer explaining what I would do under that constraint (not saying that this is the best solution, as I would use constant keys with maps).

Still assuming, that you ultimately want to generate a json-like `String` as input for your test candidate, I would create a class that prints itself to json format. Be aware, that I only tested for Object-arrays, not primitive arrays! List, Map and Set types are also not included, but you can add them yourself, if you like.

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class JSON {

    public static final Object UNDEFINED = new Object();

    public String toJsonThrowRTE() {
        try {
            return toJsonString();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException("I found thiz. May I keep it? :)", t);
        }
    }

    public String toJsonString() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Field field : getAllDeclaredFields()) {
            String name = field.getName();

            // This prevents endless recursion.
            if (name.startsWith("this")) {
                continue;
            }

            Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();

            if (fieldType.isPrimitive()) {
                // No need for the first field to have a ',' before it.
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    sb.append(",\n");
                }

                // This is cumbersome, but I have no cleaner solution.
                sb.append(name).append(": ");
                switch (fieldType.getTypeName()) {
                    case "int":
                        sb.append(field.getInt(this));
                        break;
                    case "long":
                        sb.append(field.getLong(this));
                        break;
                    case "boolean":
                        sb.append(field.getBoolean(this));
                        break;
                    case "char":
                        sb.append("'" + field.getChar(this) + "'");
                        break;
                    case "double":
                        sb.append(field.getDouble(this));
                        break;
                    case "float":
                        sb.append(field.getFloat(this));
                        break;
                    case "byte":
                        sb.append(field.getByte(this));
                        break;
                    case "short":
                        sb.append(field.getShort(this));
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                String value = valueToString(field.get(this));
                if (value != null) {
                    // No need for the first field to have a ',' before it.
                    if (first) {
                        first = false;
                    } else {
                        sb.append(",\n");
                    }
                    sb.append(name).append(": ").append(value);
                }
            }
        }

        return "{\n" + indent(sb.toString()) + "\n}";
    }

    public String valueToString(Object value) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException,
            IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {

        if (value == null) {
            return "null";
        } else if (value == UNDEFINED) {
            return null;
        } else if (value instanceof JSON) {
            JSON childJson = (JSON) value;
            return childJson.toJsonString();
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            return "\"" + value + "\"";
        } else if (value instanceof Character) {
            return "'" + value + "'";
        } else if (value.getClass().isArray()) {
            Object[] array = (Object[]) value;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            boolean first = true;
            for (Object o : array) {
                if (first) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                sb.append(valueToString(o));
            }
            return "[ " + sb.toString() + " ]";
        }

        // Everything else is just toString.
        return value.toString();
    }

    public List<Field> getAllDeclaredFields() {
        List<Field> allFields = new ArrayList<>();

        // We start with the current class, and stop at JsonStringBuilder.
        // After that, the fields are Object fields, and we don't want those.
        Class<?> currentClass = getClass();
        while (JSON.class.isAssignableFrom(currentClass)) {
            // We want to order the fields from the most general to the most specific,
            // so we must add the new fields at the start.
            List<Field> declaredFields = Arrays.asList(currentClass.getDeclaredFields());
            List<Field> childFields = allFields;
            allFields = new ArrayList<>(childFields.size() + declaredFields.size());
            allFields.addAll(declaredFields);
            allFields.addAll(childFields);

            currentClass = currentClass.getSuperclass();
        }

        return allFields;
    }

    public String indent(String toIndent) {
        return toIndent.replaceAll("(?:^|(\\n))", "$1\t");
    }
}
```

All objects you derive from this class will print themselves to json on command. This is the most powerful I can come up with on a short notice, but I think it should do.
You can now create any POJO with constructor and such, so you can set up your test, by creating you default object and then adding the required test values on demand. Objects that are `JSON.UNDEFINED` are not printed.
Here is an example on how to use it:

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    JSON topLevel = new JSON() {
        Object msgTs = "2020-02-20T11:00:00";
        Object name = "a";
        Object[] someArray = { 7, "String intermix", 'k', 5d };
        Object iAmNull = null;
        Object undefined = JSON.UNDEFINED;
        Object someChild = new JSON() {
            int someInt = 42;
            char myChar = 'j';
        };
    };

    System.out.println(topLevel.toJsonThrowRTE());
}
```

The above "test" will print this `String` to console:

```
{
    msgTs: "2020-02-20T11:00:00",
    name: "a",
    someArray: [ 7, "String intermix", 'k', 5.0 ],
    iAmNull: null,
    someChild: {
        someInt: 42,
        myChar: 'j'
    }
}
```

Now you just have to insert this string into your Json parser or whatever you want to test. This would be your base object, which you create the same way with the `@Before` or `@BeforeAll`, depending on your junit version. And from there you can modify the object per test. Remember to declare fields that may or may not be used as `JSON.UNDEFINED`, so that you can assign a useful value, but they are not printed, unless you set them!

```java
JSON message = new JSON() {
    Object header = new JSON() {
        String msgTs = "2020-02-20T11:00:00";
    };
    Object hazmet = JSON.UNDEFINED;
    Object toy = JSON.UNDEFINED;
    // ...
};
```